# Showing continuity of a function $f$ defined on $\mathbb{C}-{0}$ at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

The only condition on $f$ is that for any non-zero $w,z$, $|f(z)-f(w)|\leq |z-w|$.
My attempt at a solution is below, however since I am new to this and it seems kind of awkward, I want to make sure what I am doing is right. I would also appreciate any tips on showing a function is continuous at a point where it is not defined and the differences between showing a complex function is continuous vs. showing a function from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$ is continuous.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Let $S$ be the punctured disk of radius
      $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ i.e. $S={(a,b)\in \mathbb{R}^2: 0<a^2 + b^2 <\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$

Taking $z,w \in S$, we have $|z-w|<2\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$,
    implying, by the assumption that
    bounds on the difference of values in the domain restrict bounds
    on difference of function values in the codomain:
$|f(z)-f(w)|\leq |z-w|<\epsilon \Rightarrow |f(z)-f(w)|<\epsilon$, completing our proof.

edit: Question: Suppose f : C \ {0} → C satisfies |f(z) − f(w)| ≤ |z − w| for all z, w $\ne$ 0. Prove that
$lim_{z→0}$ f(z) exists.

Comment: It's meaningless to say that a function is continuous at a point where it's not defined. Perhaps you mean to say that the definition of $f$ can be extended to all of $\mathbb C$ in such a way that the extended function is continuous?

Comment: No I think the question literally asks me to prove that it is continuous at a point where it is not defined, I will edit the above with the exact statement.

Comment: Based on the below, it does seem like that is what this question is really asking.

Comment: OK, proving that $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$ exists is _not_ the same as proving that $f$ is continuous at $0$. You might want to check your definition of continuity at a point.

Comment: The definition wouldn't make sense right as $|f(z)-f(0)|$ doesn't have meaning, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before showing that $f$ is continuous at $0$, you have to figure out how to define $f$ at $0$. The usual procedure is the following:

1. Pick a sequence $\{z_n\}$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ converging to $0$, and use the hypotheses on $f$ to show that $\{f(z_n)\}$ is a Cauchy sequence. Therefore the sequence $\{f(z_n)\}$ has a limit, and define $f(0)$ to be this limit.
2. Show that the definition of $f(0)$ is independent of the choice of the sequence $\{z_n\}$ converging to $0$.
3. Show that the extended function $f$ is continuous at $0$. This will be straightforward once you've done (1) and (2).

Comment: So the idea in the complex plane is to construct the limit? What makes this possible in C and not in $\mathbb{R}^2$? or is it possible in $R^{2}$ as well?

Comment: The above method works in $\mathbb{R}^2$ as well.

Comment: Do I need to add assumptions on ${z_n}$? I can't apply $f$ to $0$ terms in the sequence right? Also, with my update on the actual question, is this still the right way to go about this question?

Comment: None of the $z_n$ should be zero. That's why I said it is a sequence in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$. The first two steps in my answer (without worrying about defining $f(0)$) will also show that $\lim_{z\to 0}f(z)$ exists.